# Table not displaying data when changing page in Angular

Tags: angular, pagination, slice, ngfor

I'm trying to make a table displaying data get from an API. I manage to get the 1st page but when changing page, the data is not displayed despite I can see my data from console.log().

Here's the code to call the serice

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productsSub = this.productsService.getProducts(this.page, this.pageSize).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.products = res.data
      this.total_products = res.meta.pagination.total
    })
  }

  getPageFromService(currentPage: any){
    this.productsSub = this.productsService.getProducts(currentPage, this.pageSize).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.products = res.data
    })
  }
```

My HTML for the table

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
            <table class="table table-hover" style="white-space: nowrap">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-light">
                        <th scope="col">Thao tác</th>
                        <th scope="col">Mã QR</th>
                        <th scope="col">Hình ảnh</th>
                        <th scope="col">Mã Sản Phẩm</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tên Sản Phẩm</th>
                        <th scope="col">ĐVT</th>
                        <th scope="col">Scan</th>
                        <th scope="col">Danh mục</th>
                        <th scope="col">Phê duyệt</th>
                        <th scope="col">Giá</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tồn</th>
                        <th scope="col">Hiển thị</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cập nhật bởi</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ngày tạo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let product of products | slice: (page-1)*pageSize : (page-1)*pageSize + pageSize">
                        <th scope="row" class="icon">
                            <a href="#"><fa-icon [icon]="file" style="background: orange;"></fa-icon></a>
                            <a href="#"><fa-icon [icon]="penToSquare" style="background: orange;"></fa-icon></a>
                            <a href="#"><fa-icon [icon]="trash" style="background: red;"></fa-icon></a>
                        </th>
                        <td>QR</td>
                        <td><img src='{{product.thumbnail}}' style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></td>
                        <td>{{product.code}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.unit_name}}</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>{{product.categories}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.publish_status_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.original_price_formatted}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.qty}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="product.is_featured"><div class="on">Bật</div></td> <td *ngIf="!product.is_featured"><div class="off">Tắt</div></td>
                        <td>{{product.created_by}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.created_at}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
<ngb-pagination (pageChange)="getPageFromService($event)" class="d-flex justify-content-center" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" [collectionSize]="total_products" [maxSize]="3" [rotate]="true" [ellipses]="false" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please also add HTML that has been used for to display a table?

Comment: Just add HTML for the table

Comment: Make sure you add `Bootstrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API call from method `getProducts`, is already taking care of bringing the relevant records from the server. You don't have to repeat the same logic on UI once again. You can remove the calculations part of `*ngFor` using `slice` pipe with `page` and `pageSize` based logic.

Just keep your `*ngFor` simple

```
*ngFor="let product of products"
```

#### What was wrong?

Let's assume `pageSize = 10`

Now the user clicks on the 2nd page of navigation. It is called `getProducts` with parameters `page` & `pageSize`. It brings the next page data 10 size. Now the calculation of `(page-1)*pageSize : (page-1)*pageSize + pageSize` becomes `10` to start slicing from `10` the index. And there are no more than 10 records, nothing was displayed.

```
*ngFor="let product of products | slice: (page-1)*pageSize : (page-1)*pageSize + pageSize"
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot for your help, I've been stuck on this for hours